# Is it possible to store python sources in the cloud and to download and run them on runtime as if the module is locally present?

Tags: python, security, sgx

I would like to hide the source of my python application from the admin access (commercial app deployment).

Was thinking to store the source somewhere on a server and the wrapper of the module stored locally downloads the modules on runtime just on #import and makes them available.

Does someone know a solution supporting this use case?

Best

Comment: What's the point if the code is still downloaded locally?  You could build a simple API that takes the input from the user and returns the results without having to every share the code.

Comment: I would keep the source in the heap only. So no one can copy the source. Cloud API would not fit as I work with real time processing.